# How to stop re-creating a service inside cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

New to CF. There are multiple services in my app, out of which, one particular service to be created only first time (and not to be created each time).

I'm using below code:
`cf service service-name || cf create-service service-name`

However, it still creating the service each time, when I deploy the app. Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only run `cf create-service` once. Every time you run it, it will create a new service instance.

You want to `cf bind-service` or use `manifest.yml` to bind your services to your app. If you put the service names to bind in `manifest.yml`, it will just happen automatically. Otherwise you'd need to manually run `cf bind-service` when it's necessary, which is only really once when you initially push or after making changes to the service instance.

As to your command, it seems OK. `cf service` should return 1 if it doesn't find the service name you specified, which should trigger the second part of the command to create the service. At the same time, `cf create-service` will definitely fail if you try to create a service with a name that already exists. It'll say `The service instance name is taken: foo`. Thus if you're seeing the service instance being recreated by running that command, something probably deleted it prior. Maybe review any deployment code you have and check if something is deleting that service instance accidentally. You generally *don't* want to delete a service instance, unless you're really, really done with it. Normally, it's enough to just unbind a service.